# Is there a faster way to clean up these tiny artifacts?

Tags: artifacts

[image]

So photoscan creates a lot of artifacts and I want to remove em as efficiently as possible. I know that adding a subsurf level kind of does it but I don't want to subsurf a model that's already made up of millions of polygons. So I've just been removing each one with a little click of the smooth brush in sculpting mode. Is this how you would do it?

Comment: Could you show a closeup topography of these "defects" in editmode and objectmode?

Comment: Good idea, here's a gif showing about 4 of em (middle, bottom left, top right) http://i.imgur.com/gDkWpi7.gif

Comment: Actually uh, using 'smooth vertex' on the whole model might have done the job, a move which I thought would surely totally screw up the whole mesh. I'll go uh...cry in a corner now... Just send my Darwin award in the post

Comment: You can actually use the smooth Modifier for this, and not lose your original mesh. Then just play with the factor & repeat values.

Comment: Select all, recalculate normals and remove doubles. This would be the first thing to check here. If adding **Smooth** modifier don't forget adding it only to those verts (via vertex groups) because due to topology those areas are distorted quite much so you have to smooth those areas a lot, while others obviously not.

Comment: I didn't know there was a modifier for that! Must have looked over it many times. Although to smooth out these artifacts I've found a couple of iterations is good for my whole mesh anyway and doesn't distort it much at all. But I'll keep the modifier in mind, may use it next time. Thanks everyone